# How can I triple all hash values using #each?

Tags: ruby, hash, each

I have a hash as follows:

```
drinks = {"soda" => 3, "water" => 2, "beer" => 6}
```

I would like to show the value of each pair tripled by using `each`.

In other words, I'd like "soda" to have a value of 9, "water" to have a value of 6, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this, depending on the semantics you want. One way is to operate on each key/value pair with [Hash#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-each). For example:

```
drinks = {"soda"=>3, "water"=>2, "beer"=>6}
drinks.each { |key, value| drinks[key] = value.to_i * 3 }
=> {"soda"=>9, "water"=>6, "beer"=>18}
```

Comment: @user937531: are you sure you want to destroy the original `drinks` array? it's more difficult to reason about functions if you update variables in-place...

Answer (score 9):

`Hash[hash.map { |k,v| [k, v * 3] }]`

Comment: Just `Hash[hash.map { |k,v| [k, v * 3] }]` is sufficient, you don't need the flattening and splatting.

Comment: You did, once upon a time, need all the flattening and splatting.  I'm glad they fixed that.

Comment: for those who want yet more conciseness, facets!: `hash.mash { |k, v| [k, 3*v] }`. Still fighting to get it into the core, no luck so far though.

Comment: This is the correct answer. `each` simply is the wrong tool here.

Answer (score 3):

```
drinks = Hash[­drink­s.map { |dri­nk, value­| [drin­k, value­ * 3] }]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
drinks.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k] = 3 * v }   
  => {"soda"=>9, "water"=>6, "beer"=>18}
```